# IO in where clause

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I thought I was beginning to understand IO in Haskell until I ran into the following problem.

I have the following function, which returns type IO Float:

```
getFundPrice :: Int ->  Int -> IO Float
getFundPrice fund date = do 
                       priceList <- getFundPrice' fund date
                       let h = head priceList
                       return  h
```

The function getFundPrice' uses the takusen database library and returns a list of type IO [Float].

I'm able to successfully test the getFundPrice function with Hunit using the following:

```
  p <- getFundPrice 120 20100303
  assertEqual
    "get fund price"
    10.286 
    (p)
```

The problem that is stumping me is the following function definition:

```
lastPos :: Int -> (Shares,Float) -> Period -> Fund -> (Shares,Float)
lastPos endDate begPos [] fund  = (fst begPos, trnPrice) 
                               where trnPrice = do
                                             price <- getFundPrice fund endDate
                                             return price
```

The error I'm getting when attempting to compile is "    Couldn't match expected type `Float' against inferred type`IO Float'"

I thought the **price <- getFundPrice ** action would retrieve the price for me as it does with my HUnit code.

What's different about using this in the where clause?

Comment: Be sure you understand clearly what [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:return) does in Haskell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove the explicit type signature you will see the correct type of:

```
lastPos :: Int -> (Shares,Float) -> Period -> Fund -> (Shares,IO Float)
```

Notice the `IO Float` at the end.  You have defined `trnPrice` to be an IO action that retrieves a floating point value.  You have *not* executed that action to retrieve the value!  You can not execute that action from anywhere except for the IO monad, which `lastPos` is not in.  What you can do is:

```
lastPos :: Int -> (Shares,Float) -> Period -> Fund -> IO (Shares, Float)
lastPos endDate begPos [] fund  = do
    price <- getFundPrice fund endDate
    return (fst begPos, price)
```

Which lifts all of `lastPos` into IO.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful... as per my comment on another answer, the application I'm building has a lot of business-logic functions which could be pure, but the core data that the functions operate on all come from the database, which would result in IO everywhere. It seems as if I'll lose the benefits of purity in the business logic functions. Is there a better strategy to handle an application like this?

Comment: @Neil, it is a common misconception that if your program does a lot of IO then your program has to have IO everywhere. It just means you have to design it IO to be on the outside.  This is usually easy to do -- and it causes you to model your objects mathematically instead of operationally.  In your example, just have your business-logic functions take the core data as a parameter (they do *depend on* the core data, right? -- that makes them functions).

Comment: @Neil, or if you mean that the business logic is basically phrased as database queries, then I'm sure somebody has modeled some subset of SQL denotationally, so they can be pure *in terms* of some abstraction that can only be "evaluated" in `IO`.  Eg. `Database Int` represents an int whose value someway depends on the state of the database.  Check on hackage for such models.

Comment: Thanks @Luqui, my challenge in this case is that the `lastPos` function has five other definitions, but only one of them requires querying the database and handling `IO`. I can do it by somehow returning an indication that the one piece of info is missing (and we need to do a db query), but it does seem a little convoluted. In any event, I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

The thing about the `IO` monad is that you can never get rid of the impure *taint*.  Because your getFundPrice function is not pure, nothing calling it can be pure either.

Your function will have to have the type

```
lastPos :: Int -> (Shares,Float) -> Period -> Fund -> IO (Shares,Float)
```

If it helps clarify matters, in your where clause the `return` statement wraps the pure price value back up in `IO`. There's no way<sup>1</sup> to avoid doing this - the `IO` monad is designed not to allow it.

In fact it's exactly the same as `where trnPrice = getFundPrice fund endDate`

<sup>1</sup> actually there is a [backdoor](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/System-IO-Unsafe.html), but it's not a good idea to use it

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. The application I'm building has a lot of business-logic functions which could be pure, but the core data that the functions operate on all come from the database, which would result in IO everywhere. It seems as if I'll lose the benefits of purity in the business logic functions. Is there a better strategy to handle an application like this?

Comment: You should try to separate pure from impure parts of your code. When you worked out, how to separate the code best, it usually gets a better design wutomattically.

Comment: Well, you can still pass the data to pure business logic functions, so long as you do it inside another IO function.  Your business logic can still be pure (as it should be).

Comment: I don't mind the reference to the unsafePerformIO but in my hunt to good answers I would like a link to why this (IMHO) a bad idea (and not just a not good idea) ;). One could get an impression that using the backdoor is a common practice to this particular problem.

Comment: @Jonke I think the unsafePerformIO wiki doc should be enough to scare people off - it uses words like "indeterminate" and "core dump" =O

Comment: Thanks, my challenge in this case is that the `lastPos` function has five other definitions, but only one of them requires querying the database and handling `IO`. I can do it by somehow returning an indication that the one piece of info is missing (and we need to do a db query), but it does seem a little convoluted. In any event, I'll figure it out.